# newlfm with multiple "from" names

Tags: newlfm

I am writing a letter using `newlfm` with several "senders", as though the communication comes from several people writing as one.

When I write the following, only Kit II gets listed:

```
\namefrom{Kit}
\namefrom{Kit II}
```

How do I list both of them?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\namefrom{Kit \\ Kit II}` to set multiple names.